# Solution verification : infimum of $\{x(\alpha-x)~|~x\in(0,1) \}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

$$B=\{x(\alpha-x)~|~x\in(0,1)\},$$
where $~\alpha \in \mathbb Q $ is a fixed parameter

My attempt :

- $\alpha=0$

$$x(\alpha-x)=-x^2 $$
$$ \inf(B)=-1$$

- $\alpha<0$
  $$x(\alpha-x)\le0 $$
  $$ \inf(B)=\alpha -1$$
- $\alpha\ge1$
  $$x(\alpha-x)\ge x $$
  $$\inf(B)=0$$
- $\alpha \in(0,1) $
  $$x(\alpha-x),~~\alpha-1<0 $$ 
  $$ \inf(B)=\alpha-1$$

Comment: $\inf B = -\infty$, take $x={1 \over 2}, \alpha = -n$ and let $n \to \infty$. Perhaps you mean $\inf \{x (\alpha -x) | x \in (0,1)$ for a **fixed** $\alpha$.

Comment: @copper.hat $ \alpha$ is fixed,you are right

Comment: Your notation is non standard, when you write $\{f(x,\alpha) | x \in ..., \alpha \in ... \}$ it means **all** $f(x,\alpha)$ where $x,\alpha$ satisfy the conditions to the right of $|$. You should write $\{ x(\alpha-x) | x \in (0,1) \}$ and leave the $\alpha \in ...$ out of the right hand side.

Comment: Yup. Sounds fine!